# Get nested fieldNames from JSON object

Tags: c#, json, tree-traversal

I have a JSON that contains a list of `types`. These types have some name and some fields.

Fields have a property of `dataType` and if it's value is `object`, it refers to a another type. That type could be found by its name specified in `referenceType` property.

There is also a property named `parentType` which means the type is a child of the parentType and it contains some additional properties, but have to be considered as an object of `parentType` only.

I am trying to process this JSON to get all the nested property names for all the types present in the array.

```
{
    "types": [
        {
            "name": "User1",
            "fields": [
                {
                    "name": "name",
                    "dataType": "string"
                },
                {
                    "name": "address",
                    "dataType": "object",
                    "referenceType": "Address",
                    "isArray": true
                },
                {
                    "name": "weeklyRoles",
                    "dataType": "object",
                    "isArray": true,
                    "referenceType": "Role"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "User2",
            "fields": [
                {
                    "name": "name",
                    "dataType": "string"
                },
                {
                    "name": "address",
                    "dataType": "object",
                    "referenceType": "Address",
                    "isArray": true
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "Address",
            "fields": [
                {
                    "name": "AddressLine1",
                    "dataType": "string"
                },
                {
                    "name": "AddressLine2",
                    "dataType": "string"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "BusinessAddress",
            "parentType": "Address",
            "fields": [
                {
                    "name": "headquarters",
                    "dataType": "string"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "ServiceAddress",
            "parentType": "Address",
            "fields": [
                {
                    "name": "servicePartner",
                    "dataType": "string"
                },
                {
                    "name": "serviceType",
                    "dataType": "string"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "Role",
            "fields": [
                {
                    "name": "roleName",
                    "dataType": "string"
                },
                {
                    "name": "accessCountsObj1",
                    "dataType": "object",
                    "referenceType": "Role2"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "Role2",
            "fields": [
                {
                    "name": "roleName2",
                    "dataType": "string"
                },
                {
                    "name": "accessCountsObj2",
                    "dataType": "object",
                    "referenceType": "Role3"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "Role3",
            "fields": [
                {
                    "name": "roleName3",
                    "dataType": "string"
                },
                {
                    "name": "accessCountsObj3",
                    "dataType": "object",
                    "referenceType": "Role4"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "Role4",
            "fields": [
                {
                    "name": "roleName4",
                    "dataType": "string"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Pattern in which I am expecting the result is `<typeName>;<fieldName>.<nestedFieldName>`

Expected Output

```
[
    "User1;address.AddressLine1",
    "User1;address.AddressLine2",
    "User1;address.headquarters",
    "User1;address.servicePartner",
    "User1;address.serviceType",
    "User1;weeklyRoles.roleName",
    "User1;weeklyRoles.accessCountsObj1.roleName2",
    "User1;weeklyRoles.accessCountsObj1.accessCountsObj2.roleName3",
    "User1;weeklyRoles.accessCountsObj1.accessCountsObj2.accessCountsObj3.roleName4",
    "User2;address.AddressLine1",
    "User2;address.AddressLine2",
    "User2;address.headquarters",
    "User2;address.servicePartner",
    "User2;address.serviceType",
    "Role;accessCountsObj1.roleName2",
    "Role;accessCountsObj1.accessCountsObj2.roleName3",
    "Role;accessCountsObj1.accessCountsObj2.accessCountsObj3.roleName4",
    "Role2;accessCountsObj2.roleName3",
    "Role2;accessCountsObj2.accessCountsObj3.roleName4",
]
```

I have tried to write a recursive function to process it but it is not giving me the expected result and also does not have terminating condition.

```
public IList<string> GetKeys(JArray types, string parentType = null)
{
    var nestedKeys = new List<string>();
    foreach (var type in types)
    {
        var fields = type[Constants.Fields].ToObject<List<JObject>>();
        var typeName = type.Value<string>("name");

        var nestedKeyBuilder = new StringBuilder($"{typeName};");
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(parentType))
        {
            nestedKeyBuilder = new StringBuilder($"{parentType};");
        }

        foreach (var field in fields)
        {
            var datatype = field.Value<string>("dataType");
            if (string.Equals(datatype,"object"))
            {
                var fieldName = field.Value<string>("name");
                var referenceTypeName = field.Value<string>("referenceType");
                var referenceTypeObject = types.Where(t => string.Equals(t.Value<string>("name"), referenceTypeName))?.First();
                if (referenceTypeObject != null)
                {
                    var refTypeFields = referenceTypeObject["fields"].ToObject<List<JObject>>();
                    foreach (var refTypeField in refTypeFields)
                    {
                        var refTypeFieldName = refTypeField.Value<string>("name");
                        var refTypeDataType = refTypeField.Value<string>("dataType");
                        var refTypeReferenceTypeName = refTypeField.Value<string>("referenceType");
                        if (string.Equals(refTypeDataType, "object") && string.Equals(refTypeReferenceTypeName, currentReferenceType))
                        {
                            var refTypeNestedKeys = GetKeys(types, typeName);
                            nestedKeys.AddRange(refTypeNestedKeys);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            nestedKeyBuilder.Append($"{fieldName}.{refTypeFieldName}");
                            nestedKeys.Add(nestedKeyBuilder.ToString());
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return nestedKeys;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a NuGet that you can use to handle JSON files.

Search for Newtonsoft.Json
https://www.newtonsoft.com/json

All your problems should be solved with that

Answer (score 0):

Use newtonsoft JSON to Deseriliaze the JSON string.

```
JSON.Deserialize<IEnumerable<Type>>(jsonString);
```

This should give you an `IEnumerable` to process it however you want. Types is the class you create with the JSON properties as class properties. You can use something like this

**NOTE:** Type and Field are very vague names. Type is a c# class and therefore you should not use it to create a class of your own. You will face ambiguous errors and you will need to qualify the namespace in full to use your class. Strongly suggesting to name it something else and use the attributes to map it to the JSON string.

```
[JsonObject(Title="People")]
public class Type
{
   [JsonProperty("name")]
   string Name{ get; set; }
   [JsonProperty("fields")]
   Field FieldValue[]{ get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Newtonsoft` library to do this.
This is your POCO class.

```
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string dataType { get; set; }
    public string referenceType { get; set; }
    public bool? isArray { get; set; }
}

public class Type
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public List<Field> fields { get; set; }
    public string parentType { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public List<Type> types { get; set; }
}
```

and write the function to `DeserializeObject`

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void Read()
    {
        var sample1 = @"X:\JsonFilePath\data.json";
        var jsonString=File.ReadAllText(sample1);

        var result =JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(jsonString);
        Assert.IsNotNull(result);
    }
```

Comment: you can write `result.types.FirstOrDefault(a=>a.)`  to loop through the properties of the values.